# Javascript object not mutating when passed as param for JS function In NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Having an issue here with this function, it's meant to loop through an array and check if the items within that array are keys in the object supplied to the function and on the last iteration return the supplied object with its updates. It is meant to delete any item that's in the guarded array.

The expected behaviour is for this function to return the object omitting the guarded items, but I get the object returned untouched.

I have tried logging to the console within the if statement to see if each item was found within the object and they were.

Also I am calling this within a promise and resolve with the value, and I am writing this in a Nodejs project.

```
Bar = function(){

    var self = this;

    self.data = null;
    self.show = [];
    self.guarded = [];
    self.appended = [];

    /**
     * Transforms and returns the response data
     * @param object Object/Array
     * @return Object/Array
    */
    self.make = function(data)
    {
        self.data = data;
        // validate props
        _validateProps();

        return self.get();
    }

    /**
     * Gets response
     * @return Promise
    */
    self.get = () => {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
        {
            if(_.isArray(self.data))
            {
                for(var i = 0; i < self.data.length; i++)
                {
                    // 
                    self.data[i] = self._append(self.data[i]);
                    self.data[i] = self._show(self.data[i]);
                    self.data[i] = self._hide(self.data[i]);
                }
                // resolve with data
                resolve(self.data);
            }else if(_.isObject(self.data))
            {
                // 
                self.data = self._append(self.data);
                self.data = self._show(self.data);
                self.data = self._hide(self.data);
                // resolve with data
                resolve(self.data);
            }else{
                reject(Error('Invalid data type.'));
            }
        });
    };

    self._append = function(item)
    {...};

    /**
     * Add all items that are in shown
     * @param item Object
     * @return Object
    */
    self._show = function(item)
    {
       var list = {};
       for(var i in item)
       {
            if( self.show.indexOf(i) != -1 )
            {
                list[i] =  item[i];
            };
       }
       return (self.show.length > 0) ? list : item;
    }

    /**
     * Hide all items in guarded array
     * @param item Object
     * @return Object
    */
    self._hide = function(item)
    {   
        var list = {};
        for(var i in item)
        {
            if(self.guarded.indexOf(i) == -1) 
            {
                list[i] = item[i];
            }
        }
        return (self.guarded.length > 0) ? list : item;
    }

    function _validateProps()
    { ... }

};
```

I call the function like so.

```
var Foo = new Bar;
Foo.guarded = ["name", "age", "total_scores"];
var dataset = {...}; // could also be [{...}, {...}, {...}]
Foo.make(dataset).then(function(data){
    // do something with the data
});
```

Comment: Please remove the last if-block within the loop and move `return item;` to the end of the function body. Also, `if(item[self.guarded[i]])` can evaluate to `false` for existing properties when those property values are 'falsy', e.g. `0` `""` etc. Also, the early "shortcut" `if( self.guarded.length < 1 ) return item;` is unnecessary. Apart from those nitpicks, above `hide` function should work. Perhaps your guarded array is empty?

Comment: @le_m Still get the same behaviour, the guarded array isn't empty.

Comment: Well, the `hide` function itself works as intended. The issue must be with how you invoke this method or how you initialize `self` and `self.guarded`.

Comment: @le_m I'm calling a function within an object which returns a new promise object and from within that promise I'm calling the _hide method (function) on the object. self is basically this, which is set at the point of instantiation.

Comment: If you're calling it inside a promise, are you sure you're waiting for it to resolve? This is why we need a [mcve]

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, i wait for it to resolve, you can take a look at it now, have added code to make it more self explanatory, the show method which does almost the same thing as the hide works perfectly.